# Android App Bundle signed with the wrong key

Tags: android-studio, keystore, sha1, google-play-console

I can't download the application in the Google Play Console, as it gives me an error that the Android App Bunlde using the wrong key SHA1, what i need to select the right key and repeat the download.

But I create in Android Studio (Build -> Generate Signed Bunlde / APK) a completely new key and still such an error. I also tried to clean and rebuild the project, it also did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Google Play Console Support on this issue and they will be able to reset the key for you.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.